# Minor GC causes Stop the world pauses in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

**Language:** Java

I am not sure whether Minor GC causes all the application thread to wait until the GC process completes in java. Please shed some light.

Comment: That's runtime-dependent...and you haven't specified a language.

Comment: @nneonneo: i was talking about java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's implementation-dependent.

If you're using the hotspot VM you can print information on GC STW pauses via `-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime`. If you want to print all STW pauses (not just GC ones) you can use `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics –XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` [[source](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html)].

Other JVMs may behave differently. A commonly cited example is Azul's Zing and their pauseless collector - although it actually does have pauses, but those are constant-time.

Also, do note that there is no invariant relating wall time spent in GC to GC-STW pauses. I.e. STW time could be shorter, equal or longer than GC time.